# How to check the pathname with a default id

Tags: javascript, jquery, href

I would like to check my pathname to highlight my current tab in Jquery

In this case, I have 4 pathname :

- '/'
- '/groups/#{group.id}
- '/tasks'
- '/groups/#{group.id}/task_board

And I want to write a script like this to execute it. But currently, my tries are not working.

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname;
var hash = window.location.hash
if(pathname == '/' || pathname == '/groups/'hash'/' ){
  alert('yo');
} else if(pathname == '/tasks' || pathname == '/groups/'hash'/task_board' ){
  alert('ya');
} else{
  alert('none');
}
```

Note: this is in the header, so I don't know the group_id, so I need to catch it into the current page. Do you know a simple way to do that.

Comment: `if (a == b || c)` checks if either `a == b` is true or `c` is true (not whether `a` equals either `b` or `c`). Since your string is non-empty, the first `if` condition is always true in your code.

Comment: Thanks @Cameron I made the correction, but it's only working for the first condition, how I can define a default id into the condition ?

Comment: Also bear in mind that the hash in your urls will not be part of the `pathname` if it's not properly escaped by `%23`, but rather be in `window.location.hash`

Comment: pathname get the complete path of you route.. I mean if you're in localhost the path value could be  /C:/Users/[USER]/[FOLDER]/[FILENAME] so you if statement always will be wrong. (If you're doing in localhost) what value has pathname?

Comment: Thanks, I've try with your advices, with %23 and 'hash', But it's still not working at this time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like that :

```
  var pathname = window.location.pathname;
  var group = pathname.split("/")[2]
  if(pathname == '/' || pathname == '/groups/'+ group ){
    alert('yo');
  } else if(pathname == '/tasks' || pathname == '/groups/'+ group +'/task_board' ){
    alert('ya');
  } else{
    alert('none');
  }
```

Note that group will catch your group.id to inject it into the href

Answer (score 1):

if(pathname == '/' || **pathname ==** '/groups/#id/' ){

Answer (score 0):

You need to sort out your conditional test.

Your if condition should look like:

```
if(/\/tasks/g.test(pathname) || /\/groups\/.*\/task_board/g.test(pathname) )
```

Here I have used a [regular expression](https://regex101.com/) so that you can match the string no matter what ID you are looking for:

The pattern `/\/groups\/.*\/task_board/g` means, '/groups/ **ANYTHING** /task_board/'